# How to restrict a user from selecting exacly 3 options an RecyclerView List

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've created a RecyclerViewList but I need to set a limit to the list!. I need to restrict it to 3 max selections.

**MY LIST**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

List<String> itemTitles;
SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray; // for identifying: in list which items are selected
OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener;
int selectedItemCount;
private int lastSelectedPosition = -1;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> itemTitles, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener)
{
    this.itemTitles = itemTitles;
    sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.listener = listener;

    selectedItemCount = 0;
}



@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);
    return new RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemTextView.setText(itemTitles.get(position));

    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(position))
    {

        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(114, 47, 55));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 100));
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemTitles.size();
}



/******** View Holder Class*/
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView itemTextView;
    public TextView alert;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        itemTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!sparseBooleanArray.get(getAdapterPosition()))
        {
            if (selectedItemCount > 3) {
                sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(),true);
            }
            listener.selectedItemCount(selectedItemCount); // calling the method in main activity Because: in our case mainActivity our created interface for clicklisteners
            notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
        }
        else // if clicked item is already selected
        {
            if (selectedItemCount < 3) {
                sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(),true);
            }
            sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(),false);
            listener.selectedItemCount(selectedItemCount); // calling the method in main activity Because: in our case mainActivity our created interface for clicklisteners
            notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
        }

    }
}


public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener{
    public void selectedItemCount(int count);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me your onClick code must be changed to this:

```
    if (!sparseBooleanArray.get(getAdapterPosition()))
    {
        if (selectedItemCount < 3) {
            sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(),true);
        }
        listener.selectedItemCount(selectedItemCount); // calling the method in main activity Because: in our case mainActivity our created interface for clicklisteners
        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
    }
    else // if clicked item is already selected
    {
        sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(),false);
        listener.selectedItemCount(selectedItemCount); // calling the method in main activity Because: in our case mainActivity our created interface for clicklisteners
        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

Comment: I think `selectedItemCount++` or `selectedItemCount--` is needed when there is change in the sparseBooleanArray. Hope that helps!